# How do I convert the "largest value in a Vec" example in the Rust book to not use the Copy trait?

Tags: vector, rust

I'm trying to accomplish an exercise "left to the reader" in [the 2018 Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch10-02-traits.html). The example they have, 10-15, uses the `Copy` trait. However, they recommend implementing the same without `Copy` and I've been really struggling with it.

Without `Copy`, I cannot use `largest = list[0]`. The compiler recommends using a reference instead. I do so, making `largest` into a `&T`. The compiler then complains that the `largest` used in the comparison is a `&T`, not `T`, so I change it to `*largest` to dereference the pointer. This goes fine, but then stumbles on `largest = item`, with complaints about `T` instead of `&T`. I switch to `largest = &item`. Then I get an error I cannot deal with:

```
error[E0597]: `item` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:24
  |
6 |             largest = &item;
  |                        ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
7 |         }
8 |     }
  |     - borrowed value only lives until here
  |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 1:1...
```

I do not understand how to lengthen the life of this value. It lives and dies in the `list.iter()`. How can I extend it while still only using references?

Here is my code for reference:

```
fn largest<T: PartialOrd>(list: &[T]) -> &T {
    let mut largest = &list[0];

    for &item in list.iter() {
        if item > *largest {
            largest = &item;
        }
    }

    largest
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write `for &item`, this destructures each reference returned by the iterator, making the type of `item` `T`. You don't want to destructure these references, you want to keep them! Otherwise, when you take a reference to `item`, you are taking a reference to a local variable, which you can't return because local variables don't live long enough.

```
fn largest<T: PartialOrd>(list: &[T]) -> &T {
    let mut largest = &list[0];

    for item in list.iter() {
        if item > largest {
            largest = item;
        }
    }

    largest
}
```

Note also how we can compare references directly, because [references to types implementing `PartialOrd` also implement `PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html#impl-PartialOrd%3C%26%27b%20B%3E), deferring the comparison to their referents (i.e. it's not a pointer comparison, unlike for [raw pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html#impl-PartialOrd%3C*const%20T%3E)).

Comment: It's worth noting that this would normally idiomatically be written as `list.iter().max().unwrap()`

Comment: for item in list {} works as well, without .iter(), interesting. Who may help to explain it?

Comment: @Charlie木匠 You may want to read up on [`for`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/keyword.for.html). Also note that [`&[T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html) implements `IntoIterator`.